# Advancing to Next Slide when current slide has multiple videos

Tags: video, keynote

I'm new to Keynote, and I'm happy to have created a slide with multiple embedded videos that auto-play thanks to the animate functionality. While the videos look great on the first pass, if I want to go back to this slide at the end of my presentation, Keynote "sees" each video and the animation as something to toggle through. What I want is for the arrow buttons to ignore the videos all together and to be able to toggle back and forth without getting caught up in the video content.

The closest I've come to resolving this issue is putting the whole document on "self-playing", but the maximum delay is too short for my comfort. I love how slick it looks on the first play though, but if I wanted to go back to another slide at the end of my presentation, I'll get tangled up in the video/animation on this slide.

Is there a way to make the presentation ignore the videos/animation while navigating through slides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> - <kbd>▼</kbd> (Shift - Down Arrow) to advance through slides without triggering slide elements (animations, video playback etc.).